# AnkhSVN see recent change

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I have just installed AnkhSVN, and it works great, I just have one question. If someone else in the project commits a change to a file, is there anyway for me to see this WITHOUT updating the project? If I change something a small red box shows up on that file in Solution Explorer, is there any way to get something like that when a file on the SVN is n newer version that on my local copy? In case that doesn't work. Is there anyway to see all changes that was made since last I updated. So I can keep track on whats going on in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tab called 'Recent Changes' in the 'Pending Changes' window that facilitates just that. See also http://ankhsvntips.net/post/1478971385/recent-changes-auto-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Google Code project. This way, you can easily keep track of any update or member of the project directly on the project's Google site.

Setting up a Google Code project is easy and pretty straight-forward. Since you already have AnkhSVN on Visual Studio, the only thing would be to link the Google Code project to your local project.

You can follow this as a guide : [Google Code project using Visual Studio and AnkhSVN](https://code.google.com/p/bilpool/wiki/ConfigureAnkhSVNForVisualStudio)